# Class inside a struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am getting flustrated with two errors and I have absolutely no idea what is wrong.

```
#ifndef ListElements
#define ListElements

#include "RentalObjects.h"

struct RentalList{
ObjectBase* content;
RentalList* Next;
};
#endif
```

All the time I get this error:

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.

The RentalObjects.h file features a declaration of the ObjectBase class, which looks as follows:

```
class ObjectBase{
protected:
    char Make[16];
    char Model[16];
    int Year;
    float PricePerDay;
    Booking* Availability;
public:
    void SetMake(char* value);
    void SetModel(char* value);
    void SetYear(int value);
    void SetPrice(float value);
    bool DisposeBookings();
    bool Book(int Start,int End);
    char* GetMake();
    char* GetModel();
    int GetYear();
    float GetPrice();
    ~ObjectBase();
};
```

I'd be grateful for a tip.

Comment: Most likely you missed a `;` at the end of one of a class definition (or somewhere else) inside RentalObjects.h, or otherwise caused ObjectBase to be undeclared due to a syntax error

Comment: can we see the whole `RentalObjects.h` ? does it have include guards? does it include something else? maby recursive includes?

Comment: Sure, I had multiple classes in it but now I removed them, so take a look: http://pastebin.com/WQfJuCah

Comment: What about `Booking`. Is there a declaration for it?

Comment: What is this "Booking" thing? Learn to forward-declare but not define pointed-to classes. You don't need to know what a "Booking" to define your class ObjectBase. Similarly, you don't need to know what an "ObjectBase" is to define your class RentalList. Just forward declare. #including the files that define those classes will inevitably get you into a circular mess.

Comment: Yeah, I just left it out before posting. Here is the whole file:
http://pastebin.com/8ZWZGwys

Comment: RentalObject.h includes ListElements.h, ListElements.h includes RentalObject.h, this wont work. break the cycle with forward declare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring pointers or references, you don't need the whole class/struct definition.

Instead of:

```
#include "RentalObjects.h"

struct RentalList {
    ObjectBase* content;
    RentalList* Next;
};
```

you could do:

```
class ObjectBase;
struct RentalList {
    ObjectBase* content;
    RentalList* Next;
};
```

this could get you out of a circular include, which might be what's causing your broblem

Comment: I did as you suggested and it sadly didn't help. Moreover all headers are #ifndef secured so I suppose it should get circularly included (I'm guessing).

Comment: make sure you are breaking all circular references. the include guard protects you from infinite loop in the compiler, but it still wont work, the second time a header tries to be included, it wont be, and the symbols wont be defined

Comment: Ok, you were right, it worked finally. Thanks a lot!